# How can I write an MySQL search that can compensate for misspelled data?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is there any way to write an MySQL search that can compensate for user-errors in spelling and the like?

As random examples, someone might type foo@gmial.com instead of foo@gmail.com.

Even help with search terms to help pull up relevant data from Google will be helpful.  I'm not looking for a search engine, per say, what I'm looking for is some kind of spelling aid for an administrative control panel.

Comment: You can use dictionary DB or Table. But thing is that whether the word is actually miss spelled or is it that way only. Like company names etc....

Comment: It is quite impossible task to do but if the key word is specific to any category, like mail as you mentioned, you can simply manage a data table for all the mail service provider list and search for perfect list before executing in mysql.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The topic you're delving into is called "Fuzzy Lookup". It's a big rabbit hole to jump down, depending on how precise you'd like to get. There are various methods, such as:

- soundex
- Damerau-Levenshtein distance
- Jaro-Winkler distance
- metaphone
- double-metaphone

Some references to check out:

- [PHP/MySQL small-scale fuzzy search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914671/php-mysql-small-scale-fuzzy-search)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching
- [How do I do a fuzzy match of company names in MYSQL with PHP for auto-complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369755/how-do-i-do-a-fuzzy-match-of-company-names-in-mysql-with-php-for-auto-complete)
- [Implementation of Levenshtein distance for mysql/fuzzy search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634995/implementation-of-levenshtein-distance-for-mysql-fuzzy-search)

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do the same. One of I personally like is `SOUNDS LIKE`.

Checkout the [SOUNDEX Example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0460__String-Functions/expr1SOUNDSLIKEexpr2ThisisthesameasSOUNDEXexpr1SOUNDEXexpr2.htm).